# Android Automotive supporting Android Auto & CarPlay

Tags: android-auto, carplay, android-automotive

I'm working on an infotainment system for car's and I've flashed Google's Android Automotive pulled from master branch of AOSP to my hardware. I wanted to know if anybody is working on something similar and has manage to get Android Auto and CarPlay working? I've find a couple of articles where they should be supported but when I plug in an Android or an iOS phone I just get a popup asking me if I want to open the gallery.

Comment: Since Android Automotive is suppose to outclass the capabilities of Android Auto, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because we want the same experience like before on an old infotainment system that wasn't based on Android Automotive.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get Android Auto or CarPlay working with just the AOSP. Both require custom development requiring closed software libraries and customized device driver support. CarPlay even required that you have Apple Authentication Chip integrated as well. All this info is only provided to registered partners only.